# DB::Exception: Invalid type for filter in PREWHERE: Array(String) (version 21.1.3.32 (official build))

Tags: регулярные-выражения, clickhouse

Есть таблица в кликхаус.Выполняю следующий запрос используя метод [extract](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/ru/sql-reference/functions/string-search-functions/#extracthaystack-pattern).

`select * from posts where extract(text,'(виртуальны\w{,4}\s|дата-центр\w{,4}\s)') LIMIT 200`

При выполнение запроса выходит следующая ошибка:

`Code: 59, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Invalid type for filter in PREWHERE: Array(String) (version 21.1.3.32 (official build))`

Гуглил гугл ответов не дал.Думал дело в неправильности регулярного выражения но проверил через этот [сайт](https://regex101.com) регулярка правильная.
Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Но ведь, по документации, `extract` возвращает `Array`, а `WHERE` ожидает "выражение с логическими операторами". Или что-то не так?

Comment: Мне кажется вы путаете `extractAllGroupsHorizontal`.Или я вас не совсем понимаю. В документация написано `extract` принимает `haystack` и `pattern`

Comment: В документации возвращаемое значение только под ним было подписано, вот я и подумал, что оно для всех, что выше написаны. Извините :D Прочитал описание, увидел, что возвращается строка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не могу воспроизвести ошибку - получаю *'Invalid type for filter in WHERE: String'*:

```sql
SELECT toString(number) AS text
FROM numbers(5)
WHERE extract(text, '(виртуальны\\w{,4}\\s|дата-центр\\w{,4}\\s)')

/*
Received exception from server (version 21.2.3):
Code: 59. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Invalid type for filter in WHERE: String.
*/
```

Тем не менне используйте функции [empty](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-functions/#function-empty) или [notEmpty](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-functions/#function-notempty), чтобы исправить ошибку:

```sql
SELECT toString(number) AS text
FROM numbers(5)
WHERE empty(extract(text, '(виртуальны\\w{,4}\\s|дата-центр\\w{,4}\\s)'))

/*
┌─text─┐
│ 0    │
│ 1    │
│ 2    │
│ 3    │
│ 4    │
└──────┘
*/
```

Comment: Благодарю ваш ответ мне помог ! Не мог ли бы вы объяснить почему функция `empty` помогла ?

Comment: @Raharasomaha давайте посмотрим на docs [WHERE clause](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/ru/sql-reference/statements/select/where/): *"Результат выражения должен иметь тип UInt8."* - UInt8 это другими словами boolean. *empty* проверяет пуста строка или нет и возвращает 1 или 0.